# Clear all notification from notification bar of any android device using appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

How to clear all notification from notification bar in android using appium in any of the android devices.

I tried

```
    MobileElement clearallnotification=null;
    driver.openNotifications();
    try {
        clearallnotification= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@content-desc, 'Clear all notifications')]"));
        clearallnotification.click();
    }catch(ElementNotFoundException e) {
        clearallnotification= driver.findElementById("com.android.systemui:id/delete");
        clearallnotification.click();
    }
    driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
```

But It works only for specific devices how to make it generic for all kind of devices?

Answer (score 0):

The below code will do that. It worked for me.

from appium import webdriver
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
from time import sleep
import pytest

class TestScrollAndroid:
    "Class to run tests against the Chess Free app"

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def driver(self, request):
    "Setup for the test"
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '8.1.0'
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Realme 2 Pro'
    desired_caps['noReset'] = True
    desired_caps['udid'] = '2032609e'
    desired_caps['allowTestPackages'] = True
    # Returns abs path relative to this file and not cwd
    desired_caps['app'] = "D:\\Chess Free.apk"
    desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'uk.co.aifactory.chessfree'
    desired_caps['appActivity'] = '.ChessFreeActivity'
    #desired_caps['autoWebview'] = True

    #calling_request = request._pyfuncitem.name
    driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    def tearDown():
        print("Tear down the test")
        driver.quit()

    request.addfinalizer(tearDown)
    return driver

def test_scroll_notificaion(self,driver):
    driver.open_notifications()
def test_clear_all_notification(self, driver):
    driver.open_notifications()
    if(driver.find_elements_by_id("com.android.systemui:id/clear_all_button"))
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("com.android.systemui:id/clear_all_button")
        element.click()
    assert(not driver.find_elements_by_id("android:id/title"))
```

Comment: http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/system/open-notifications/ try this...it will open your notifications and rest code can be modified into java. Ping me if you have any problem. The id won't change from device to device because it is an android functionality. It may change because of the version. You have to take care of it that means more "||" checks.

Comment: This is what is tried 
driver.openNotifications();
  try {
   clearallnotification= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@content-desc, 'Clear all notifications')]"));
   clearallnotification.click();
  }catch(ElementNotFoundException e) {
   clearallnotification= driver.findElementById("com.android.systemui:id/delete");
   clearallnotification.click();
  }
  driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);

Comment: What Error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Webdriver.IO here is the solution:
$('~Clear,Button').click()